# Dominant rational maps and compositions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, terminology, birational-geometry

According to many books (and also to Stack project, see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01RI ), a morphism $f\colon X\to Y$ between schemes is said to be *dominant* if the image is dense in $Y$.

One can then generalise this to rational maps $X\dashrightarrow Y$, which are equivalence classes of $(U,\psi)$, where $U\subset X$ is open and dense, and $\psi\colon U\to Y$ is a morphism.

One classical result is that if you have two rational maps $f\colon X\dashrightarrow Y$ and $g\colon Y\dashrightarrow Z$, such that $f$ is dominant and $X$ is *irreducible* (in which case $Y$ is also irreducible), then you can define the composition $g\circ f\colon X \dashrightarrow Z$.

This is no longer true if $X$ is not irreducible: you could have some irreducible components of $X$ contracted onto points not defined under $g$. If $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily irreducible one can define the composition  $g\circ f\colon X \dashrightarrow Z$ in the case where **each irreducible component of $X$ is mapped dominantly onto an irreducible component of $Y$.**

It then seems to me that when considering rational maps between arbitrary schemes (or algebraic varieties), not necessarily irreducible, the main notion would be the above one (in bold). Is there some kind of standard name for this? Like *"strongly dominant"* or something like this? Does someone has some references / books where this notion is discussed? Why is the classical definition of dominant not the above one?

Comment: Without reference to irreducible components: it's equivalent to the condition: for every subset $U$ of $X$ with non-empty interior, $f(U)$ has non-empty interior. (More rigorously: for some/every representative $f':V\to Y$ of $f$ with $V$ open dense in $X$, for every non-empty open subset $U$ of $V$, $f'(U)$ has non-empty interior in $Y$.) It seems equivalent to the existence of an open representative $V\to Y$ for some dense ope $V\subset X$.

Comment: Note that "strongly dominant" would be clumsy since it shouldn't be dominant (for instance the inclusion of an irreducible component of $Y$ into $Y$ should satisfy the condition). If you want dominant as well, it's just a combination of two properties.

Comment: good remark: it seemed stronger than dominant to me but it is in fact neither stronger nor weaker. It corresponds to ask that the preimage of any dense open subset is dense.

Comment: Maybe *"generically open"* makes the job, as for a morphism (defined on a dense open subset) it means the set of $x\in X$ at which $f$ is open is dense.

Comment: Generically open seems nice. I just realised that "strongly dominant" was used by Hanspeter Kraft in his notes "Algebraic Transformation Groups – An Introduction" (available on his webpage)